# XBMC Sleep Mode

Tags: power, kodi

I've been looking to get a Pi as an easy way to setup a TV box for my living room. I'd like to set up XBMC and be able to put it to sleep when not in use.

I've found the Sleepy Pi addition but I was wondering how most people use the Pi in terms of power when using it as a TV box. Should I just leave it on or should I unplug it?

Comment: I leave mine on. It likely uses less electricity than your cable box. Over the course of a year it works out to about a dollar a year.

Comment: This has been asked and answered before. Can't find it unfortunately!

Comment: The Pi uses ~3W @ 10c/kWH it would cost 26c PA. Don't bother.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you are using the latest model Raspberry Pi 2, power consumption is around 3.5 ~ 4 watts when the Pi is running. So the power consumption will be very less when Pi is in sleep mode.

You can just leave it ON. Also, manually unplugging and plugging it every time kills the pleasure of using it as a TV box.

Comment: It doesn't actually have a real "sleep mode", but the power consumption is less when it is not doing anything.